# how to get the next 2 bytes from a bytearray after a match

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, regex

I have a bytearray:

```
s = b'\x01\x80\x00\x04_\xa9\xa20\x01\x19\x00'
```

I want to search and find:

```
\xa9\xa20
```

Then once found I want to get the next 2 bytes after that.  In this case:

```
\x01\x19
```

I've tried:

```
m = re.search(b'[(?:\xa9\xa20)]{2}',s,re.DOTALL).group(1)
```

But get an Index error:

```
m = re.search(b'[(?:\xa9\xa20)]{2}',s,re.DOTALL).group(1)
IndexError: no such group
```

Comment: Why do you put a group inside `[]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a corrupt regex pattern here since you put a `(?:\xa9\xa20)` non-capturing group into a character class (repeated twice). However, just removing the square brackets won't help.

You can fix the code using

```py
import re
s = b'\x01\x80\x00\x04_\xa9\xa20\x01\x19\x00'
m = re.search(b'\xa9\xa20(.{2})', s, re.DOTALL)
if m:
    print(m.group(1)) # => b'\x01\x19'
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/EwQyWS)

That is, rather than unsuccessfully trying to match two consecutive occurrences of `\xa9\xa20` bytes, match a `\xa9\xa20` byte sequence *once* and then match and capture any two bytes after them with `(.{2})` **capturing group**.

Comment: Is there a way of adding a variable for the number of bytes to get {2}.  Let's say if I wanted to set x = 2 and use it as b'\xa9\xa20(.{x})' (tried this way but doesn't work)?

Comment: @magicsword Yes, use something like `x = 2` and then just concatenate the parts: `m = re.search(b'\xa9\xa20(.{' + str(x).encode('utf8') + b'})', s, re.DOTALL)`, see [a Python demo](https://ideone.com/mnSTQm).

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

`\\xa9\\xa20(\\xa?\d+\\xa?\d+)`

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lCNejq/1) in Regex101